# Unfortunately, Callisto has stopped working

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, nullpointerexception

So when I try and run my code in the emulator, the app background pops up then closes giving me the dialog, "Unfortunately, Callisto has stopped working"
I have no idea what is wrong other than it gives me a null pointer exception (line 49) but there is nothing at line 49

XML

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/callisto_heading" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bClasses"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Classes" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:onClick=""
   />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bSettings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Settings" 
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
    android:onClick=""  
 />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java
    package android.callisto.com;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class CallistoActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
 Button settings_button;
 Button classes_button;
 Button home_button;
 CheckBox notif_cb;
 CheckBox math_cb;
 CheckBox science_cb;
 CheckBox ss_cb;
 CheckBox english_cb;
 CheckBox language_cb;

 boolean notif,math,science,english,ss,language;




 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    //settings layout
    notif_cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbNotif);
    math_cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbMath);
    science_cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbScience);
    ss_cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbSS);
    english_cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbEnglish);
    language_cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbLang);
    home_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bHome);

    notif = true;
    math = true;
    science = true;
    english = true;
    ss = true;
    language = true;

    home_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

        }
    });        

        //notifications

    //main layout
    settings_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSettings);
    classes_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bClasses);

    settings_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        }
    });
}
```

}

FYI the app was loading last night.. Thanks for any help and please remember I am new to Android programming. Thank you.

Comment: where is line 49 in your code? and post logcat result when application is crashing

Comment: Quite clear to me what is causing this, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is here

```
 home_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bHome);
```

in layout file there is no `bHome`

Comment: This indeed causes the error, but TS does not understand the android activity design pattern I guess. See my answer for more detail.

Comment: @NickL we are not here to write complete code for him! as he need to put some effort.

Comment: You are right. But since there wasn't really anything wrong in his code, except for the fact that it was in one activity and he used setcontentView for changing layout, I decided to split the code (copy/paste). I think he still would not be able to solve the problem just with your answer, since he probably wouldn't really understand WHY the button was not in the layout file. To his understanding, it was.

Answer (score 0):

The problem probabaly is, that you are using the setContentView() for displaying different screens. You should not use this method for changing screens,you should use a different activitys for this.

Usually, you only set the contentView ONCE in the oncreate, per activity.

Your R.layout.main layout probabaly does not contain the 'home' button, but the r.layout.settings layout does.

First you are loading the main layout at this line: `setContentView(R.layout.main);` But since this layout file does NOT contain the home button, `findViewById(R.id.bHome);` will return `null`. After that, calling a method on this returned value,  `home_button.setOnClickListener();` in your case, will cause a NullPointerException.

What you should do is the following:

Create an activity for your main layout:

```
public class CallistoMainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
 Button settings_button;
 Button classes_button;
 Button home_button;
 CheckBox notif_cb;
 CheckBox math_cb;
 CheckBox science_cb;
 CheckBox ss_cb;
 CheckBox english_cb;
 CheckBox language_cb;

 boolean notif,math,science,english,ss,language;




 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //main layout
    settings_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSettings);
    classes_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bClasses);

    settings_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                   CallistoSettingsActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
```

And an activity for your Settings layout:

```
public class CallistoSettingsActivity extends Activity {

 Button home_button;
 CheckBox notif_cb;
 CheckBox math_cb;
 CheckBox science_cb;
 CheckBox ss_cb;
 CheckBox english_cb;
 CheckBox language_cb;

 boolean notif,math,science,english,ss,language;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);


    //settings layout
    notif_cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbNotif);
    math_cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbMath);
    science_cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbScience);
    ss_cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbSS);
    english_cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbEnglish);
    language_cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbLang);
    home_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bHome);

    notif = true;
    math = true;
    science = true;
    english = true;
    ss = true;
    language = true;

    home_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            //You could either use finish() to finish the current activity, and return to the previous CallistoMainActivity on the stack.
            //Or you could simply start the main activity again by using the startActivity() method you see in the onclicklistener on the settings button.
        }
    });        
}
```

What happens now, is when you click the settings button in the main activity, the settings activity will be shown. When you click the home button in the settings activity, the settings activity will be finished, and the user will be returned to the previous activity on the stack; which is the main activity.
Also do not forget to define the settingsactivity in your AndroidManifest.xml

EDIT: Another thing you should note, that if there is an error 'at line x' but there is nothing at line x in your code, then the code running on your Android device, is not the same as the code you are looking at in your editor. So that might be the reason it was running last night, but not anymore.